# Character data is represented incorrectly like this (?????) in sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a problem..

I work with ASP.NET and After I add a data (Arabic language) to my form via the browser it added to the SQL Server Management Studio like this (???????) even when I retrieve the data entered by the browser, Although there is no problem when I add my Arabic data via SQL Server Management Studio direct.

(there is no problem with English data)

Comment: Please check the datatype in the database of the table column, it should be nvarchar type instead of varchar for uni-code type.Arabic language is taken as uni-code type by SQL Server while storing the characters. And pass the values using sql parameters else you have to add " N'test' " for the values compulsorily.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere along the way your changing the charactertype to something else, that is probably Standart ascii.
It is impossible to know where exactly since we don't have hany information about that, but I would guess that in your Backend things are messed up, try commenting out your code and just echoing the values to see if they are already wrong at that stage.

Maybe change the Stringtype to utf-16
That should support any chars you throw at it